# Vector Autoregression forecasting with large dataset

Tags: training, forecasting

I am trying to use VAR to forecast electricity price for a whole day and I have a dataset with over 20000 observations (price for every hour) from 2015-2017.

My first intuition was to select 19975 observations as train:
model = VAR(train) and model.select_order() (looking at the information criterion - AIC,BIC etc..) function to select the number of order. After training I would evaluate it by forecasting it with rolling forecasting.

However, I have read that when training your model it is better to train it with the most recent observations instead of using the entire dataset. But I have also read that the more past data you have the better your forecasting.

My question is should i use a small number of recent observations instead and if so how much ?

Thank you very much